# Is there a way to have custom defined friendly URLs with WCF without IIS?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, config

Is there a way to have custom defined friendly URLs with WCF without IIS?

In particular I'm looking to do something like this via an app.config hosted in my own Windows service:

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "foo/{id}")]
public string GetFoo(string id)
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes sure - host this inside your own NT Service, and in your `app.config`, define a http base address. The URI templates you define in your service contract will be off that base address:

```
<services>
   <service name="YourNamespace.YourServiceClass">
      <host>
         <baseAddresses>
             <add baseAddress="http://YourServer:9091/Services/" />
         </baseAddresses>
      </host>
      <endpoint address="" 
                binding="webHttpBinding" 
                contract="YourNamespace.IYourService" />    
   </service>
</services>
```

Then your URI template will be added to this base address, so in that case, you `GetFoo` method would be callable at:

```
http://YourServer:9091/Services/foo/42
```

**Update:** I just recreated this here, and the problem is this: your URI template defines a parameter called `{id}`, but the method you apply this URI template to doesn't have any parameter called `id` in it's parameter list:

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "foo/{id}")]
public string GetFoo(string fooID)
```

You need to make sure those things match! With the given URI template, you need to change your method declaration to:

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "foo/{id}")]
public string GetFoo(string id)
```

(see the parameter - it's name is now `id`) and then you should be fine - at least it works just fine for me.

Comment: I tried this but it still doesn't use my custom WebGet UriTemp.  Only if I host the service DLL in IIS or without a windows service via F5 Visual Studio Debug.  I think the setting that makes it work for IIS is: `<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b13f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>`

Comment: I am using VS2010 and C# by the way

Comment: @wcf guru needed: updated my answer - I hope that's the issue you had - at least it works for me, now.

Comment: Thanks will this work with me calling the URL via my web browser?  I'm getting Sendera:ActionNotSupportedThe message with Action '' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver. Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).

Comment: I would appreciate it if you can help me with the new error here, thank you so much for your help so far: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211909/strange-error-when-trying-to-start-my-wcf-service-with-webhttpbinding