# Strange error when trying to start my WCF service with webHttpBinding 

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'm getting this strange error when I try connect to my WCF with webHttpBinding service **from a web browser**:

> Sendera:ActionNotSupportedThe message with Action '' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver. Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).

My app.config:

```
<services>
  <service name="MyNamespace.MyService">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:9091/MyService/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="MyNamespace.IMyService" />
  </service>
</services>
```

My method simply looks like this:

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "foo/{id}")]
public string GetFoo(string id)
{ ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK - I would expect you're probably missing the endpoint behavior needed - try this config:

```
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>    
<services>
  <service name="MyNamespace.MyService">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:9091/MyService/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint 
        address="" 
        behaviorConfiguration="web"
        binding="webHttpBinding" 
        contract="MyNamespace.IMyService" />
  </service>
</services>
```

Comment: THANK YOU! You have helped me immensely, I really appreciate your help.  Everything works now.  By the way you seem to know everything there is to know about WCF, do you have a good book recommendation?

Comment: @wcf guru needed: the two books I read myself back to back are [Learning WCF by Michele Leroux Bustamante](http://www.amazon.com/Learning-Hands--Michele-Leroux-Bustamante/dp/0596101627/) and the more advanced [Programming WCF Services by Juval Löwy](http://www.amazon.com/Programming-WCF-Services-Juval-Lowy/dp/0596526997)

Answer (score 0):

When you updated your method from `GetFoo(string fooID)` to `GetFoo(string id)`, did you also update your contract in `IMyService` with the updated parameter name of `id`?

Reference of your previous question: [Is there a way to have custom defined friendly URLs with WCF without IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211326/is-there-a-way-to-have-custom-defined-friendly-urls-with-wcf-without-iis)

Comment: That actually wasn't a problem I had, I had just typed the problem wrong when posting the question.